# How to get Project Location in Visual Studio Project Template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parameters, msbuild, project-template

I want to create a custom Visual Studio Project Template.
Can I read the location path, that is specified in the New-Project-Wizard in Visual Studio?

My goal is to import a file with custom build targets. This file located in a directory relative to my new project.

I tried it this way:

```
<Import Project="..\Deployment\custom.targets" />
```

But when creating a new project from my template it will point to a temporary users directory .

On MSDN I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that indicates there is no parameter that contains the location path. I can't believe that...

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not need my custom targets when instanciating a project I solved this with a condition:

```
<Import Project="..\Deployment\custom.targets" Condition="exists('..\Deployment\custom.targets')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the solution path in the ProjectFinishedGenerationg event:

```
public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
        {

            string solutionPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(project.DTE.Solution.FullName);

        }
```

Comment: This won't work. If your adding a new project to an existing solution the path of the solution is not the path of the project being created.